# Cannot Search | Featured | Popular | Newest | Favorites in wordpress working

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

I am working on a Wordpress 3.8 site hosted by Parallels and uploaded via the plex panel.

When I want to search, featured, popular, newest favorites a new plugin, I get an error message saying

> Warning: An unexpected error occurred. Something may be wrong with WordPress.org or this server’s configuration. If you continue to have problems, please try the support forums. (WordPress could not establish a secure connection to WordPress.org. Please contact your server administrator.) in /var/www/vhosts/fixskinproblems.com/httpdocs/wp-admin/includes/plugin-install.php on line 77

I had spent 2 days on googling with this issue.

Comment: Have you contacted your hosting company's support?

Comment: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?296565-Cannot-Search-Featured-Popular-Newest-Favorites-in-wordpress-working&p=715225#post715225

Comment: Disable all plugins -- by moving the `wp-content/plugins` folder to a different location if you can't get to your `wp-admin` pages -- and try the site. If it's working, then a plugin is at fault. In that case, re-enable the plugins one at a time until the issue recurs. That will tell you *which* plugin is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are trying to install a new plugin. You may need to contact your host about this problem.  If you have FTP access to your site, try downloading the plugin from the Wordpress website, and manually uploading it to the server.

Comment: http://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-search-featured-popular-newest-favorites-in-wordpress-working?replies=1#post-5107052

Comment: http://forum.parallels.com/showthread.php?296565-Cannot-Search-Featured-Popular-Newest-Favorites-in-wordpress-working&p=715225#post715225

Comment: @Sandeep You can search for and download plugins at http://wordpress.org/plugins/. Do I understand correctly that your problem is you can't search for plugins to install on your WordPress site?